# How do I fix authorization error 403? which I am getting while authorizing my api on "developer.google.com/oauthplayground"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I am trying to create an api which will send users mails (using nodemailer).
On the final stage of Google OAuth2 steps (after providing client id and client secret and selection of gmail account) I' am getting an error 403 "Authorization error". For this issue I have created several project and apis but the result is same.

```
Error 403: access_denied
The developer hasn’t given you access to this app. 
It’s currently being tested and it hasn’t been verified by Google. 
If you think you should have access, contact the developer (sebastianrobi29@gmail.com).
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: yes, I have already gone through all those processes

Comment: do you have any api restrictions set?

Comment: no, It is set to external?